# Updating constructor value with Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In the code below I want to update a `knockout.js` variable with a value passed through a function call added the ViewModel prototype. However this does not seem to give a syntax error. code such as `this.modelType = newModelType` also does not seem to work as the `ko.observable` is not updated. using `this.modelType = ko.observable(newModelType)` does not seem to bind back to the view properly.

```
MyApp.ViewModel = function() {
    this.modelType = ko.observable();
};

MyApp.ViewModel.prototype = {
    foo: function(newModelType) {
         this.modelType(newModelType);
    }        
};
```

Any ideas how to update a field defined in the constructor via a parameter passed to a prototype function?

Comment: Can you post a sample in jsFiddle or more code perhaps?  Your syntax is correct in your sample.  The only question is whether the value of `this` is appropriate when you are calling it.

Comment: Your code above should work. Why do you think it does not work?

Comment: I don't think that it is working because the input element on in the view bound to "modelType" does not change the value displayed. Also, in another function when I use the value of modelType it does not appear to have the updated value.

Comment: @Martin: check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9M6bX/ . It works. I think the problem is your bindings